# Feature file contains ( and /. How escape?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java, cucumber-serenity

I use cucumber 6.
My feature file contains:

When dialog ws1000 Log In Handheld ( user: test / workstation Id: stp50)

How write step definions functions for this? How escape?

> @When("dialog ws1000 Log In Handheld \( user: {} \/ workstation Id:
> {})") - nor working((

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: i don not know, step not found(((

Answer (score 0):

You are using [a Cucumber Expression](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/cucumber-expressions/). So you can escape the `(` with a `\` and because you are using java you also have to escape the `\` which means that you end up writing `\\(`.

```java
@When("dialog ws1000 Log In Handheld \\( user: {} \\/ workstation Id: {})")
public void dialog_ws1000_log_in_handheld_user_test_workstation_id_stp50(String user, String workStation) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
}
```